# Create a W3C validated anchor link with target="_blank"

Tags: css, xhtml, target

I have the following piece of HTML that creates a new window when clicked:

```
<a href="/path/to/site" target="_blank">glide by the people</a>
```

Problem is that it does not pass the W3C validator. How do I create a link like the above that does validate?

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to other people, but this question makes no sense to me. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: @Adam - create a simple HTML page with an <A> link element that has "target=“_blank” attribute. The try to validate it against W3C validator. You will get an error (IIRC because target attribute is deprecated)

Answer (score 9):

Use this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhmtl1/DTD/xhmtl1-transitional.dtd">
```

1.0 transitional accommodates some html "legacy" code, including target="_blank".

Comment: Is there any way to get the same functionality w/out resorting to the transitional doctype?

Comment: Not without using javascript. (see the post by @ajm below) Reason why this was removed was due to accessibility and user interaction. Users want control over that stuff, not popups. :)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming strict XHTML, you would bind an onclick event to the anchor in question. Something like:

```
<a href="/path/to/my/link" onclick="window.open('/path/to/my/link');return false;">My link</a>
```

One would also argue that you should be binding that onclick action separately with external JavaScript due to progressive enhancement and separating behavior from your markup, but that's the basic way to go about it.

Comment: Minor gripe: DRY! replace the URL in the onclick event handler with `this.href`. Also, move that whole thing into a JavaScript file instead of cluttering up your HTML.

Answer (score 6):

<s>I think you're asking the wrong question. The target attribute is not valid in strict XHTML 1.0 no matter whether you insert it with JavaScript or just have it in the server response.</s>

If you really want that attribute, you have to use a different doctype, but that's not really the right answer either.

You should ask yourself why you want the attribute. I'm guessing you're trying to create a new tab or window. Needless to say this is generally considered bad design (it takes control away from the user), but if you really want to do it, you could do it with JavaScript.

Here's how:

Keep your links but add a special class, e.g. "popup" to them. Then add a line of JavaScript (preferably using a framework like jQuery or Prototype to make it easier) that takes all links with that class and gives them an on-click handler that results in the creation of a new tab/window and cancels the default action (i.e. stops the link from working as a link). That will still annoy people as it overrides the expected behaviour, though.

What you should not do is replace the links with dummy links and rely on JavaScript for the links to work.

Disregard that. The `target` attribute is no longer deprecated in HTML (the living standard or "5", depending on whether you follow WHAT WG or the W3C). The correct answer today is to just replace your DOCTYPE with this:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Note that it no longer has to be uppercase nor actually look like a full SGML DOCTYPE declaration. It's just a vestigial artefact identifying the document as standards compliant HTML.

Comment: I don't have a lot of external links, just one in fact. My document was completely  validated accept for the new window part. I have seen a lot sollutions here. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 5):

1. Validation isn't the be all and end all of coding quality.
2. Some things are "standard" in browsers without being a w3c standard.
3. Using a bit of JS is a little overkill when the function already exists.

Comment: What if W3C validation is a coding standard requirement?

Comment: Indeed. Validation is a great tool, but it's not like W3C are gods that get everything right. The standards aren't perfect

Comment: @Lemurik: Every browser understands and accepts target="_blank". Just because it's not in the W3C standard doesn't make it incorrect.

Comment: All are good points, but on the other hand standards are standards for a reason. There are reasons of usability and accessibility not to use target="_blank". (It breaks the back button, some user agents, etc.) Forcing new windows to open is a bad idea.

Comment: @Machine It doesn't mean that it isn't still a bad idea.

Comment: @Machine - you are missing my point. The user may have a perfectly legit need to comply with W3C validator whatever his, your or mine opinion on the accuracy, usefulness and goodness of said validator is.

Comment: @Joshua. Bring it up with the W3C then. :) I take the contrary view. Window management should be under the control of the user. What about the visibility impaired? Don't break my back button, bro.

Comment: @ghoppe @Lemurik: The W3C standard also says that the <script> element must have an type-attribute. It isn't, however, up to the client to decide the type when requesting a resource. The server responds with a type. This attribute is IGNORED by the server. It was put into the HTML-spec since the commitee sought to replace JavaScript in the future. My point is, just because something is in the standard doesn't mean that it is neccessary, or even correct. A lot of interests are involved when they are written.

Comment: @ghoppe I agree with you that not using _blank has some real benefits. I also don't like when this decision is taken for me. But should it pass validation? Yes.

Comment: @Machine If you don't like it if the decision is taken for you, and the W3C has agreed with you that this is a bad practice and should be discouraged in the future, then why do you think _it should pass validation_ with the updated spec? Past bad decisions should not be written in stone.

Comment: @ghoppe since the response to failing _blank (look at this thread it's enough proof) is all too often writing a link that doesn't even work w/o javascript I'd say that we're better off if it does pass.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just one or two links, you can do it inline with

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"></a>
```

More than that and you probably want one of the js solutions above.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

> target="_blank"

use:

> onclick="this.target='_blank'"

Note the single quotes inside of the double quotes. This solved the validation problem for me, without having to redefine the doctype.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it with W3C strict validation.

The solutions are:

- Transitional doctype as already mentioned
- A different validator (e.g. [CSE](http://www.htmlvalidator.com/htmlval/whycseisbetter.html))
- Use JavaScript to replace "_blank" - see http://www.ajaxblender.com/open-links-new-window-w3c-valid-target-blank.html (the link shows how to do it real neatly with jQuery - I am pasting the 2 examples below).

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('A[rel="_blank"]').each(function() {
               $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
          });
     });
     // ...OR...
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('A[rel="_blank"]').click(function() {
               window.open($(this).attr('href'));
               return false;
          });
     });
```

- Also, as per [this doctype page](http://doctype.com/validate-html-w3c-set-target-attribute-aelement), HTML5 should allow target atrtribute to be validated, fow what it's worth.

Comment: 1.) You shouldn't use the markup names as uppercase. Use lowercase instead. 2.) There's a syntactic error in this code: there's a "greater than" sign before `false`. 3.) You should indicate clearly that these are 2 separate solutions in the jQuery code.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - what's the reason for #1?

Comment: of course, both works in jQuery as it handles tags in a case-insensitive way. It's rather a naming convention; for XHTML-compatibility, you should rather use lowercase tags in HTML-formatting too, as XHTML documents [can only use lowercase tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.2). So you should stick to these conventions in your JavaScript codes too. :) [Here are some interesting aspects](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Should_you_use_upper_case_or_lower_case_HTML_tags), and [here's another one](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/lowercase/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `rel="new-window"` attribute to the link (instead of `target="_blank"`)
2. add jquery script to head of page and add the following snippet

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('a[rel="new-window"]').click(function(){
               window.open(this.href);
           })
       });
   </script>
   ```

(Please note that as I typed this in the stackoverflow textbox, I haven't tested it.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the proposed here solutions with adding the "target" attribute through JavaScript are completely standards compliant!

The thing is that according to the W3C DOM Level 1 specification the interface [HTMLLinkElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-35143001) DO have target attribute, although the A element from HTML 4.01 specification do not have it.

So it's invalid to write "target" attribute in html file, but is valid to add it to the document tree later via DOM interfaces using JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a requirement for Accessibility or Cross-Platform Interoperability, you likely want to validate your web page. There is a nice document answering the question about "why validate?" posted by W3.org http://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html

IMHO, it shows you care about your audience, when you take the extra time to validate. Then, you will have pages that show virtually the same on IE, Opera, Safari, and Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="..." onclick="return !window.open(this.href)">...</a>
```